# php, mysql single query for multipe columns distinct values

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

Is it possible to retrieve records using single query in case like:

```
id  title         tags
1   First         yellow,blue
2   Second        green, yellow,red,
3   Third         black,purple
```

What I would like to do is select all records where keyword yellow appears.
The result should return two records "First and Second"

Comment: Try `select * from table where tags like '%yellow%' `

Comment: why isn't a proper 1-N structure used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use `REGEX` to get exact search

```
SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE 
    tags REGEXP '[[<:]]yellow[[:>]]'
```

Or you can also use `FIND_IN_SET()` function

```
SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE 
    FIND_IN_SET('yellow', tages) > 0
```

NOTE: `FIND_IN_SET()` function won't work correctly if tags not symmetric comma separated, if `tags` have white space between `,` then it would create problem

Comment: FIND_IN_SET() works perfectly. All my tags are imploded before being stored.